# How can I condense a description of a web designer/developer's work into a one-liner?

Tags: editing, business-writing

How can I condense this sentence into a one-liner?

Being alone on the project, this web designer/developer held the responsibility of
 - communicating with the client and the end-users,
 - defining web application requirements,
 - giving advice on business procedures,
 - designing the web application,
 - developing the web application,
 - testing the web application and
 - updating the web application.

Maybe there are certain words I haven't thought of which could help condense this? Also, I suppose this kind of sentence already exists somewhere because it basically describes the workload of a lone web designer/developer, but I can't seem to find anything.

Comment: I'd have thought in this day and age, doing all these things would be normal for any software developer working either as an independent, or in a small organisation. It doesn't make much difference whether the software uses/relies on the web. You still have to do everything unless you're in a bigger company where they let you concentrate on the bits you're best at, but even there I think you'd be expected to at least know how to do all the other bits.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes, that's why I want to find a SHORT way of saying all this, because it doesn't deserve a lengthy description..

Comment: @Shawn: Well, just say you're experienced in all aspects of web development. The only specific bit you need to add is something you haven't actually listed. That's the matter of exactly how far you interact with the clients - discussing cost benefit analysis with them, negotiating functionality, charges and delivery dates, etc. with the guys at the top? Or just talking to the clerical staff who actually *use* the software? You do all the "techie" stuff; you just need to say how far you reach (or don't, as the case may be) beyond that.

Comment: If you want to critique your sentence here and ask for improvements, then we need a sentence. Don't be lazy, show us that you have worked on it.

Comment: Agreed with @John Smithers.  Shawn, critique questions are to critique existing writing.  Please [see our guidelines](http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/questions/166/what-are-the-guidelines-for-asking-for-a-critique-of-my-work/167#167) and edit appropriately or this will be closed.  Thanks!

Comment: @justkt I edited the question, does this fit the guidelines better?

Comment: This is an older question. It's been bumped by the system because it's been retagged, as per [this](http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/q/534/26) meta post.

Answer (score 3):

The designer/developer will communicate with clients to define requirements and advise on business procedures in order to support their design, development, testing and updating of the completed web application.

Comment: In this sentence, it is not obvious that the designer/developer is the one doing the design, development, testing and updating. It only says that his work *supports* these tasks..

Comment: edited to make more specific

Answer (score 3):

The web designer/developer is responsible for end-to-end web application development and maintenance, which includes liasing with clients and end-users to define the business requirements and procedures.

Answer (score 1):

"*Designer's name here* has *x* years of experience in successfully creating and optimizing over *x* web sites for customers across a spectrum of organizations and requirements."

This sounds like you hope to promote this designer to prospective customers. Some guidelines:

Personalize it. Using the name, even if you're repeating it, to make the association of written piece to responsible party more concrete. The capacity is no longer generic, and you're also willing to put the name in your printed/online materials.

Offer specifics. The years and number of projects are examples. These help solidify your claims that the person is qualified and go a long way to convincing people that the person can handle the role.

Use strong verbs. I chose the words "creating and optimizing." These are powerful. The person can create (in other words carry the whole load), but also optimize (listen, adjust, and improve).